# intercept zip file download request to view contents?

Tags: http, zip, https, download-manager, file-download

user 'A' downloads a zip file from a web server via HTTP/HTTPS,
and after downloading he immediately deletes that zip file from server.
In this scenario,can user 'B' (not having direct access to source server & user 'A' machine) view the content of the downloaded zip file :

- Immediately while downloading is going on ,
- After 10 days ,

  by looking the router/gateway logs or via some download monitoring programs?

if someone can do so then,what client side security measures can be applied to ensure confidentiality .

Comment: you say "via HTTP/HTTPS" but which is important.  HTTPS transmissions would be more useless to anyone intercepting them.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately with no access to the server: If HTTPS is used and the viewer/attacker has not got the server SSL key then no. If HTTP is used and the traffic is not encrypted in another manor (wireless WPA comes to mind), then the data packets for the zip file will be available to recover the zip file.

After 10 days with no access to the server: no

Immediately with access to the server logs: The server is all powerful in this situation and could have done anything with the request information. All bets are off depending on the server type, version and configuration not to mention the competency of the operator.

After 10 days with access to the server logs: Same as above. The amount of time that a server holds its logs and what is in them is an unknown factor